# Elasticsearch query data group by second

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a log index in ElasticSearch which timestamp include millisecoind, but I need only to get first record for each second. My index look like this:

```
{
...fields,
timestamp: "2021-10-28T11:13:15.080Z"
},
...,
"2021-10-28T11:13:15.180Z",
"2021-10-28T11:13:15.280Z",
"2021-10-28T11:13:15.380Z",
"2021-10-28T11:13:15.480Z",
"2021-10-28T11:13:16.080Z",
...,
"2021-10-28T11:13:17.080Z",
...,
"2021-10-28T11:13:18.080Z",
...,
"2021-10-28T11:13:19.080Z",
```

There are milliseconds. How can I query to get result group by second (first record in each group):

```
{
...fields,
timestamp: "2021-10-28T11:13:15.080Z"
},
{
...fields,
timestamp: "2021-10-28T11:13:16.080Z"
},
...
"2021-10-28T11:13:17.080Z"
"2021-10-28T11:13:18.080Z"
```

I tried Date histogram aggregation but it return separate buckets which include only timestamp lists without another fields I need.

My current ElasticSearch version: 7.15.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware if it's doable with a single query and without additional processing but you can try these 2 ways:

1. Add a `min` sub-aggregation into your date histogram on "id" (if you have one and it's ascending) or "timestamp" field; it will point to first doc in each bucket. Then pull the docs with a second query.
2. Add a "timestamp_seconds" field (rounded to seconds) when indexing and then [collapse](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/collapse-search-results.html) results on it.

Comment: You can also compute `timestamp_seconds` on the fly as a runtime field, it will be slower though.

Comment: Thank you. I used date_histogram with some sub aggregations. It solve my problem.